# Как работать с разными базами данных в Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, запрос, eloquent

Имеется 2 БД. Одна *sqlite* вторая *mysql*. По умолчанию назначена *sqlite*. Я хочу внести данные в *mysql* базу. Делаю запрос

```
Firm::on('mysql')->create($request->all());
```

Но запрос идет не в *mysql*, а в *sqlite* из-за этого появляется ошибка, что нет такой таблицы.
Так тоже на работает

```
$firm->name = $request->name;
    .....
    $firm->url = $request->url;

    $firm->on('mysql')->save();
```

Как мне сохранить данные в *mysql*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `setConnection()` для установки соединения с которым будет работать Ваша модель. В Вашем варианте:

```
$firm->setConnection('mysql');

$firm->name = $request->name;
    .....
    $firm->url = $request->url;

    $firm->on('mysql')->save();
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое за ответ. Я нашел как делать http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections У меня теперь другая проблема вылезла. У меня валидация идет через `request` и до контроллера не доходит запрос, а обрывается на валидаторе, т.к. он обращается к базе sqlite. Ищу щас, как в route прописать установку `connection`. Не сталкивались с этим?

Comment: @Konstantin может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890952/laravel-change-database-connection-for-a-specific-url

Comment: Спасибо огромное!